# How to get correct words on time?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions, spoken-english

My first language is not English, though I read/write and talk (sort of), more than average fluency, I am not able to recall exact word on time. I really get no idea which word to use and I end up with long unavoidable pause.

How can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: Smile, paraphrase and remember that this will get gradually better. And even native speakers sometimes don't have words for what they want to say.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you shared shows your English vocabulary is weak. To improve your vocab, you need to practice daily .

You can do this by reading English newspapers and identify new words from them . Find the meaning of those words from dictionary.

Daily you have to keep a target of learning five new words and try to make sentences of your own using these words. Like this, your vocabulary will become powerful and then the day will not be far when at a wink of an eye you will easily recall the words from your mind's dictionary.

You can also read magazines, listen to English radio channels, English Songs, Watch English Movies.

One more important exercise you can do is : Everyday take any five sentences and then think them in your mind in your mother tongue and then translate those five into English. The moment you feel you are missing the word. Find the dictionary and get the word.

Practice this daily. Your English will improve to an extent. Here's an example of how can you do this.

Example : Suppose your mother tongue is Gujarati, now think one sentence in your mind in Gujarati say : **મને પિક્ચ્રર જોવી ગમે છે.** Now try to translate this in English in your mind : It will be like this : **I love to see movies.**

This translation is correct but perfect word is not used. To get the perfect word for **જોવી** take a Gujarati - English Dictionary and then check this word there. You will find its meaning is to watch. Hence, the correct sentence would be : **I love to watch movies.**

So, to sum up things that will be required to solve your problem are as follows :

- Gujarati to English Dictionary
- English to Gujarati Dictionary
- English Newspapers
- English News
- English radio Channels
- English Movies and songs ( if interested)
- Target of learning five new words daily and using them in sentences of your own.
- Thinking five sentences in your mother tongue and then translate them in English in your  mind.

**Note : Here,I have taken Gujarati language just as an example.Replace it with your mother tongue.**

Comment: Hi, I like your answer and by the way I do understand Gujarati as well. Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure.Hope this helps to get rid of your problem.